# Should custom deallocation functions consider compatibility with generic containers?

Tags: c, containers, void-pointers, generic-programming

In C if you want to have generic containers, one of the popular approaches is to use `void*`. If the generic containers hold some custom struct that has its own deallocation function, it's likely going to ask for that function:

```
struct Foo {...};
Foo *Foo_Allocate(...);
void Foo_Deallocate(const Foo*);


int main(void)
{
    /* Let's assume that when you create the list you have to
       specify the deallocator of the type you want to hold */
    List *list = List_Allocate(Foo_Deallocate);

    /* Here we allocate a new Foo and push it into the list.
       The list now has possession of the pointer. */
    List_PushBack(list, Foo_Allocate());

    /* When we deallocate the list, it will also deallocate all the
       items we inserted, using the deallocator specified at the beginning */
    List_Deallocate(list);
}
```

But most likely the type of the deallocator function will be something that takes a `void*`

```
typedef void (*List_FnItemDeallocator)(const void*);
```

The problem is that `Foo_Deallocate` takes a `const Foo*`, not a `const void*`. Is it still safe to pass the function, even though their signatures do not match? Probably not, since pointer types are not necessarily the same size in C.

If that's not possible, would it be a good idea to have all deallocator functions take a `const void*` instead of a pointer to the type they are related to, so that they would be compatible with generic containers?

Comment: This model offers an unsatisfying asymmetry; the client is responsible for allocating `Foo`s, but the container is responsible for deallocating them.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This is a simplistic example. Imagine cases where `List_Allocate` would ask not only for a deallocator but also for a copy/clone function. You might also offer a function like `List_CopyBack` which copies the element and does not take possession of its argument. Whose responsibility is it then to free these objects?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, assigning pointer to a different function type is not valid.

You should take a `void*` as a parameter, and perform some check inside each function to see if the given pointer matches the expected type (like checking for a magic number at the beginning of the struct).

Comment: See [the two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418354#comment13443285_10418619) [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418354#comment13443335_10418619) I left on mnunberg's answer.

Comment: @PaulManta: Well, you can either choose compile-time type-checking, run-time type-checking, or no type-checking.  You've necessarily given up on compile-time checking (unless you rewrite everything with macros), so all you have to choose between is whether you want run-time checking or not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use a magic number or 'header' to specify the destructor function. You can go quite far with this header, and even select a 'well known, registered' deallocator (in which case you don't actually need to store a function pointer, just possibly an integer index into an array), or have a 'flags' section within your header which specifies that this contains an 'extended' deallocator. The possibilities are quite far and quite fun.

So your list 'headers' would look something like this

```
#define LIST_HEAD struct list *next; struct list *prev; short flags;
struct list { LIST_HEAD };
struct list_with_custom_deallocator { LIST_HEAD void (*dealloc)(void*); };
```

Now, actually answering your question.. why not just define a common header type, and have your deallocators take a pointer to *that* type (in my example, a `struct list*`) and then cast it to whatever specific relevant type -- or even better,maybe heuristically determine the actual structure and deallocator from the `flags` (as hinted by Binyamin).

Comment: This seems quite complicated considering how simple the requirement is: *be able to specify a deallocator*. And it also seems quite error prone. If I wanted to avoid taking `void*` in all my deallocators, I'd rather just make wrappers around these deallocators, and make the wrappers compatible with the generic ocntainer.

Comment: C isn't my language of choice, so I might be wrong, but it seems that its philosophy is something along the lines of *the programmer knows best, the programmer is always careful* (hence all the manual management of almost everything). Using flags to determine the type and gain a bit of safety just seems (to me) to add some overhead that is neither intuitive, easy to maintain, or even very characteristic of the language's philosophy.

Comment: The _programmer knows best_ philosophy is applied by you supplying your own flags. Higher level languages actually implement this form of header and magic number for their higher level objects (so they are all "variables", but they have different properties depending on the flags they define, and thus different deallocation/allocation/mutation behavior. This isn't only about safety but also about knowing what type of object you are dealing with. This is the core of any 'object' or 'generic' system: provide what's common in a well known format, followed by a differntiation specification